# Excel plugin in c#

Tags: c#, excel, plugins, connection

I have written an excel plugin which creates a workbook and add connection object to it. But, as soon as I add connection to workbook it starts downloading data from source. How can we avoid data downloading and just add connection to workbook. Below is snapshot of my code:-

```
Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
app.Visible = false;
WorkBook workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(1);
string connectionString = "DATAFEED;Data Source=" + odataURL + ";Namespaces to Include=*;Max   Received Message Size=4398046511104;Integrated Security=Basic;User ID=" + tokens[0] + ";Password=" + tokens[1] + ";Persist Security Info=false;Base Url=" + odataURL;
workbook.Connections.Add2("Feeds", "MyFeeds", connectionString,"ExecutedReport", Type.Missing,  true, Type.Missing); // this step downloads data from source. How to avoid it.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting [`Workbook.UpdateRemoteReferences`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._workbook.updateremotereferences%28v=office.14%29.aspx) to `False`.

More details are on this Microsoft's [Excel Development site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193266%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

Comment: After adding Workbook.UpdateRemoteReferences to false it downloaded the data.